# Spring Cloud Config - throws invalid private key error

Tags: configuration, spring-cloud

Reason: Property 'spring.cloud.config.server.git.privateKey' is not a valid private key. I have generated SSH key with follwoing command - ssh-keygen -m PEM -t rsa -b 4096.

I have generated the keys with multiple ways like putty gen, Git bash etc., but still I am getting invalid private key.
[image: I am using windows 10 pro edition and github repo for centralized] configuration. attached the configuration file and error log file[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue After adding the "passphrase" to properties file as highlighted in th attached message. "passphrase" will be generated at the time of generating keys.
[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, could you please provide issue

Comment: @PAA I was getting the error like "Property 'spring.cloud.config.server.git.privateKey' is not a valid private key" while authenticating to Git repo to read the properties. Later I figured out and added a new property "passphrase", which we create while generating the RSA keys.